# The implications of symmetry + uniqueness in electromagnetism

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, symmetry, parity

I have tried to follow ["Symmetry, Uniqueness, and the Coulomb Law of Force" by Shaw (1965)](https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1119/1.1971482) in both asking and solving this question, but to no avail. Some of the mathematical arguments there are a bit too quick for me but, it suffices to say, the paper tries to make the "by symmetry" arguments of introductory electromagnetism rigorous.

My question is the following: Consider a 1D situation in which I have a charge distribution which obeys $\rho(z) = -\rho(-z)$. Then I conclude that there must exist another solution obtained from my original solution via this symmetry: $E'(z) = -E(-z)$. But by the uniqueness of solutions to electromagnetism problems we have $E'(z) = E(z)$ so that we have $E(z) = -E(-z)$. But this is absurd, since it implies that the electric field everywhere points toward the origin which makes no sense for a distribution obeying $\rho(z) = -\rho(-z)$ (dipole) so that it should point in one direction everywhere. Where have I erred in "using symmetry"?

Edit: After HTNW, I think I follow. In particular, we first observe that the symmetry $\rho(z) = -\rho(-z)$ is equivalent to saying that the system must be invariant under a reflection $\rho(z) \to \rho(-z)$ followed by a "flipping" of charge $\rho(-z) \to -\rho(-z)$. These transformations being symmetries of the system mean that we can obtain another solution to the problem by performing (an active series of transformations) $E(z) \to E'(z') = E'(-z) = -E(z)$ (this step is analogous to Shaw equation (2)) followed by $E'(z') \to E''(z') = -E'(z')= -(-E(z)) = E(z)$. Then, by uniqueness, it must be that the solution $E''(z') = E(z')$ so that, inserting this into the last equation and using $z'$ = $-z$ we find $E(-z) = E(z)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've missed a minus sign. Say you have a charge distribution $\rho(x),$ which generates an electric field $E(x).$ Now consider the charge distribution $\rho'(x)=\rho(-x)$ (spatially flipped). Then $\rho'$ generates the electric field $E'(x)=-E(-x),$ where $E'$ is $E,$ spatially flipped. When you spatially flip a vector field, you not only "move" each vector $E(x)$ from the position $x$ to the position $-x,$ but you *also* have to flip the directionality of the vector itself (draw a picture!). Now, if you negate the charge distribution to $\rho''(x)=-\rho'(x)=-\rho(-x),$ you flip the electric field (without "moving" the vectors in space) to $E''(x)=E(-x).$

In the case where $\rho''(x)=-\rho(-x)=\rho(x)$ (note that this allows configurations other than a dipole; e.g. a quadrupole), then you have $E(x)=E(-x),$ which makes sense.

We've hit upon a general principle: when dealing with fields of geometrical objects (here a field of vectors $E(x)$), a transformation of space not only moves the objects between the points of space, but may change the objects themselves. Scalars like charge density are geometrically points and don't pick up the "extra" transformation. Vectors have more geometry (they are line-like), so they do. For other objects (tensors, spinors) you will have other transformation rules (more or less derived from the rule for vectors).

Comment: Thank you; I'm going to spend some time thinking about this but I think this answers my question. In the meanwhile -- do you have any suggestions for sources which rigorously justify the appropriate transformation rules?

Comment: Please also see edits if you can!

Comment: @EE18 The priming of the spatial coordinate seems to be confusing you. If the field of the charge distribution $\rho(x)$ is $E(x),$ then the field of the distribution $\rho'(x)=-\rho(-x)$ is $E'(x)=E(-x).$ I don't prime the $x$ because all I'm doing is considering two (possibly different) charge distributions in the "same" space. Then, if the charge distributions *are* the same ($\rho(x)=\rho'(x)=-\rho(-x)$), by uniqueness of the solution the electric fields are the same ($E(x)=E'(x)=E(-x)$), and I get a useful equation.

Comment: I think I understand now. Certainly I follow your argument though I think you're using the passive point of view whereas I was hoping to use the active point of view. I think my edit makes me correct now -- if you don't mind checking I'd appreciate it, but either way I'll accept you right now.

Comment: No, I *am* using an "active" convention, because I am constructing *new* charge/field distributions $\rho',E'$ in the *same* coordinate, instead of representing the same distributions $\rho,E$ in a new coordinate. A passive point of view doesn't really work for this problem anyway, since you can't handle inverting charge. Your equations still seem confused to me.

Comment: If you have the chance I am following the convention in that paper linked (by Shaw). The priming of the coordinate is I think just an extra step (and I prime it inside the new, primed function).

Answer (score 0):

> *"Then I conclude that there must exist another solution obtained from my original solution via this symmetry: $E'(z) = -E(-z)$..."*

That's not a conclusion, that's an assumption. And then you found a counterexample, a dipole distribution of charge has an electric field that does not obey such relation. So it is an assumption that is not true in general.

The primed electric field function does not, in general, obey the Gauss law of electrostatics with the same charge density, like the first solution does:

$$
\partial_z E(z) = \frac{\rho(z)}{\epsilon_0}.
$$

It is easy to check for the proposed function - using the definition, we get

$$
\partial_z E_p(z) = - E'(-z).(-1) = \frac{\rho(-z)}{\epsilon_0},\tag{*}
$$

where $E_p$ is the proposed other solution and $E'(-z)$ is value of derivative of function $E(z)$ at position $-z$ (we can write it is also as $\partial_z E(-z)$).

This result (*) is consistent with the Gauss law only if $\rho(z)$ is an even function. If it is non-zero function, then electric field points everywhere either towards the origin, or away from it, so it changes sign at 0, so electric field is an odd function. If density vanishes everywhere, then electric field can be any constant function.

All this has a simple mathematical reason - a function and its derivative do not have the same parity, except when the function is constant. Derivative of a nontrivial even function (electric field has the same direction everywhere) is odd (dipole distribution of charge), and vice versa.

Question the assumptions.

Comment: I ask because the paper I mentioned says precisely that the kind of conclusions I make here should be correct.